# Merge two domains with 301 redirect

Tags: domains, 301-redirect, multiple-domains

I have two domains (`.com` and `.co.uk`) with different websites. In `.co.uk` domain I have a good ranking and my idea is to redirect the `.co.uk` domain to `.com`. I think I have to use 301 redirect.

My questions is, I have two different websites, the two websites are different but with the same categories and some products, I have to create only one redirect of home to home or a should create other pages like similar products, categories and other similar pages in both sites?

The created backlinks usually goes to homepage, so I thought I just needed to redirect the homepage.

I don't want to lose the ranking and have problems with Google crawl.

Comment: Why did you create two websites with the same content?

Comment: The idea are have only one website, but thanks anyway Zistoloen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want remove from Google index the `.co.uk`, you should apply 301 redirect from all pages on `.co.uk` to all similar pages on `.com` (even if all your backlinks come to your `.co.uk` homepage). Addition to SEO, don't forget to think about users.

Comment: Ok. So I gonna create all the 301 redirect of all the categories, pages and some similar products, create the .htaccess. Can  I leave the old website in the .co.uk Host? Or is better delete after create all this things. Cheers Zistoloen.

Comment: If all your 301 redirect are performed, you can delete files on `.co.uk` host. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, you should find the best matching redirect for any URL - this will give search engine visitors the best experience. Google likes good experience for their users, too :)

i.e. it would definitely be better to 301 every single product page to its respective product page at the actual site.

Comment: Yes, definitely i gonna create all the redirect and try to create the best experience for the users :) Cheers Peterp